# No puedo enviar un único dato via $.ajax a controlador MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy enviando un solo valor desde mi formulario a un controlador MVC de ASP.NET utilizando $.AJAX, solamente envio un valor de mi formulario y dependiendo del valor que mande así sera la respuesta que obtendré del controlador desde un JsonResult, mi problema es que no mando nada, es decir, el controlador no puede realizar ninguna validacion porque no recibe ningun valor, este es mi codigo:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var dui = $("#inputText1").val();                    
                var datos = { "id" : dui};

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/PruebaHTML",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  datos,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.respuesta == "OK")
                            alert("Muy Bien");
```

y ya probé con `JSON.stringify(datos)` pero no recibo nada, como ven en la funcion success si recibo "OK" hago una acción especifica en caso de no recibir "OK" haría otra función pero no la pongo para no llenar de código, este es mi controlador

```
public JsonResult PruebaHTML(string valor)
        {
            RespuestaJSON datos = new RespuestaJSON();
            if (valor=="algo")
            {
                datos.respuesta = "todo bien";
                datos.accion = "datos agregados exitosamente";
            }

            if (valor=="pablo")
            {
                datos.respuesta = "OK";
                datos.accion = "datos actualizados exitosamente";
            }

            return Json(datos , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

`RespuestaJson` es una clase cuyos atributos corresponderan con mensajes que enviare desde este controlador (peticion explicita del cliente), pueden ayudarme y decirme que hago mal al mandar ese dato hacia controlador o es que no regreso bien el dato desde el controlador ? gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: si andas aprendiendo ASP.net MVC, échale un ojo a un workshop que hice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ojo aquí:

```
var datos = { "id" : dui};
```

ese "id", reemplazalo por "valor"

Answer (score 0):

Quizás no estás recibiendo el dato que mandas en la variable `id`, debido al **content type** que *jQuery* envía por defecto cuando usas el método *POST*.

Recuerda que en este caso tus datos están siendo enviados usando esta configuración (que es la que *jQuery* establece por defecto):

```
$.ajax{
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}
```

¿Qué tal si intentas enviando un `contentType` como *JSON*?

```
$.ajax{
    contentType: 'application/json'
}
```